# Migration between postresql and Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

I have a Customer table in pgadmin, postgresql and Customer app in Django with almost the same Fields.

Both customer table in postresql and Customer in Django contains the `Customername`, `Paymentterms`, `QuotationTerms` and `OrderCurrency`.

How to migrate the added Django objects to the postgresql table?

Comment: Your question is not clear what you want. Please add detail information.

Comment: same table in both Django and Postgresql. how to migrate the data from Django to Postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you have an existing database schema, and now you want to make django models for it. If this is the case, you can [set the managed attribute of a model to false](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#managed). This will stop django from attempting to manage the database schema by creating and/or modifying tables.

Comment: I have an exitsint database and within it i have customer table. plus i have customer model in Django. how to add the values to customer table by using Django customer model?